# Average items in a list of tuples by value in tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

`total = [(1, 'red'), (10, 'green'), (9, 'red'), (10, 'blue'), (5, 'blue')]`

I want to be able to average the above list of tuples by color. So my expected output would be

`averaged = [(5, 'red'), (10, 'green'), (7.5, 'blue')]` or something along those lines.

I am not exactly sure how to approach this, but my only thoughts at the moment would be pretty poorly organized and I have to imagine there are better ways. I have tried to use `set` to get the uniques, but I am not quite sure how to use that and keep in mind the values and average in the first element of the tuple. Any ideas or pointers are greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you average the colors to get the result you mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also want to maintain order, you can group items and calculate the averages with a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

total = [(1, 'red'), (10, 'green'), (9, 'red'), (10, 'blue'), (5, 'blue')]

d = OrderedDict()
for count, color in total:
    d.setdefault(color, []).append(count)

d = [(sum(v) / len(v), k) for k, v in d.items()]
print(d)
```

Which gives:

```
[(5.0, 'red'), (10.0, 'green'), (7.5, 'blue')]
```

**Note:** If you are using **Python >= 3.6**, you can simply use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or a normal dictionary to group the items, since the order insertion of keys in maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Here a try , here `numpy` is used to `import mean` that will find average, and `defaultdict` is used to make dict key as colour and a list of values as its number:

```
total = [(1, 'red'), (10, 'green'), (9, 'red'), (10, 'blue'), (5, 'blue')]

from collections import defaultdict
import numpy

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in total:
    d[v].append(k)
l = [(numpy.mean(j), i) for i,j in d.items()]
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user `itertools` and `numpy` for this problem.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

total = [(1, 'red'), (10, 'green'), (9, 'red'), (10, 'blue'), (5, 'blue')]

total_sorted = sorted(total, key=lambda x: x[1])
result = []

for key, group in groupby(total_sorted, key=lambda x: x[1]):
    result.append((key, np.mean(list(map(lambda x: x[0], group)))))

print(result)
# [('blue', 7.5), ('green', 10.0), ('red', 5.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` to group the tuples by the second item after sorting the list, and then calculate the averages of the first items of the sub-lists.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
print([(sum(map(itemgetter(0), g)) / len(g), k) for k, g in [(k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(total, key=itemgetter(1)), itemgetter(1))]])
```

This outputs:

```
[(7.5, 'blue'), (10.0, 'green'), (5.0, 'red')]
```